# Unexpected behaviour of "in" in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I iterate through a `json` object, stored in `myData`
When I do:

```
for something in range(1,10):
    currentThing = "w{}".format(something)
    someData = myData["Response"][currentThing.upper()]
    for j in someData:
        c += 1
    print currentThing + " " + c
    c = 0
```

I get the expected results.
`w1` to `w9` gets counted and shows up.

However, when I add these lines

```
for something in range(1,10):
    currentThing = "w{}".format(something)
    if currentThing in myData["Response"]:
        someData = myData["Response"][currentThing.upper()]
        for j in someData:
            c += 1
        print currentThing + " " + c
        c = 0
```

It ommits `w1`, `w3`, `w4`, `w9`.
Why is that?!

Comment: what is your `myData["Response"]`?

Comment: @vittore a dictionary since `myData` is a json.

Comment: You may want to add at least a reasonably partial sample of the `json` object you load, or values of `myData`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second block of code, the if statement you added needs to convert to upper case.  Change that line to:

`if currentThing.upper() in myData["Response"]:`

Answer (score 0):

for some reason you check if the key `currentThing` is in `myData["Response"]` but proceed to fetch `currentThing.upper()` from it. 
So, checking if `currentThing.upper()` is in `myData["Response"]` instead feels like it's what you should probably be doing

Comment: a few seconds late